# Function Overloading for the standard library functions in C++

Tags: c++, overloading

I have a free function as part of a class. In the constructor for the class i am doing some `malloc` operations . So in the `destructor` i am trying to free that memory. But VS10 compiler complains that the

```
free(pointer);
```

doesn't match the signature of the free function of my class.

So question is In a class wherein if we have implemented methods which have same names as that of standard library functions . How to call one over the other.

Regards,

Comment: You might want to post the your `free` function's signature.

Comment: 1. You should be using `new/delete`. 2. The code might be useful at this end to comment further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should qualify your call to the function:

```
void YourClass::free(args) {
  ::free(your_member);
}
```

This will pick up the `free` function in the global namespace and not in your class.

`#include <cstdio>` also puts `free` and `malloc` into the `std` namespace, so `std::free` and `std::malloc` will also work.

(Use of `new`/`delete` should also be considered, as well as smart pointers.)

Answer (score 8):

You have to use the scope operator to get the correct scope of the `free` function:

```
::free(pointer);
```

Having `::` at the beginning tells the compiler to look for the `free` function at the global scope, not the closest scope which is your class.